# can't use different materials in one object (blender 2.82a)

Tags: materials

I am beginner in blender, I want to use different materials in an object.in order to do it , I have to select the face I want and assign the color but the result I see is different!

[image]

I want to create some green faces but when I assign the new material,the face gets disapeared!

[image]

[image]

I am using blender2.82a . is it a bug?

here is the file :
[image]

Comment: can you provide the blend file? Use Blend-Exchange for that: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: yes:) I uploaded it.

Comment: just try restarting blender it may be a glitch

Answer (score 0):

Im using 2.82.7, windows 10 and have had no such issues.
I opened up file, didnt change a thing, except switched workspaces and put the two 3d views in rendered and lookdev modes, seems to work fine for me.

[image]

Possibly you just need to tab out of edit to make it update a change properly.